# Как загрузить картинку в базу данных из командной строки?

Tags: mysql

Как загрузить картинку в базу данных из командной строки?

Comment: А зачем в базе хранить картинки? Может будет лучше хранить картинки на диске, а в базе - ссылку на файл?

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться функцией [`load_file()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Fload-file).

с помощью неё файл в операционной системе *gnu/linux* (вероятно, и в других *posix*-совместимых) можно «загрузить», например, так:

```
$ echo 'insert into t values(load_file("/полный/путь/к/файлу"));' | mysql ...
```

где таблица `t` создана так:

```
create table t (c longblob);
```

Answer (score 0):

ответ НИКАК. если только картинки не хранятся в base64 :)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?